# Maple: Inverse of Covariance Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, maple

Good day,

I would like to ask about the inverse of covariance matrix from the coding below (using maple):

[image: maple]

Anyone know why the inverse A can't be computed?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your formula **t** is clearly wrong because the units don't match on both sides of the minus sign. Shouldn't the first term be divided by $n^2$? If you make that change, then the matrix is invertible.

You should compute the inverse using **j:= A^(-1)**. The **inverse** command and the whole **linalg** package have long been deprecated.